# Import PixiJS as a set of modules without a bundler (error messages)

Tags: javascript, import, module, pixi.js

I'm trying to install PixiJS as a module with no webpack (for learning purpose).

for that, I used:

```
npm install pixi.js
```

Here is how my Express file looks like after I added the "pixi.js" pointer (I had to do it by myself manually):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/dist/' , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/pixi.js/dist')));
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build')));
app.use('/jsm/'  , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/jsm')));
```

Here is how I edited my HTML file

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "pixi.js": "./dist/pixi.js",
            "three"  : "./build/three.module.js",
            "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls":"./jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="module" src="client.js"></script>
```

And finally, here is how my main js file looks like:

```
import * as PIXI  from 'pixi.js';
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
```

So, I test this by adding a Pixi scene just under the import statements:

```
let app = new PIXI.Application(800, 800);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
etc...
```

But then I get this error message now:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'pixi.js' does not provide an export named 'Application'
```

The pointers to the PixiJS location in the express and html files were found by trial and error. The ones I mentioned here above are the only ones that didn't yield a 404 error message (PIXI not found), so I guess they are the ones required.
But now that PIXI is found, the console says that the module isn't exporting its components properly.

But maybe my pointers aren't right since the installation creates 3 pixi related folders in my node-modules directory: @pixi", "pixi" and "pixi.js". All I can say is that my pointers allowed the pixi module to be recognized. Any other one I tried failed.

Any help (without webpack or an external url in the html file)  would be appreciated.
I really want to install Pixi locally, as a (set of) module(s) but without a bundler.

PS: the three.js related parts that you see in the files work like a charm. PixiJS is the only one giving me troubles.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I should point to pixi.mjs instead of pixi.js.
Thanks.